# How To get values from text box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

This code isn't mine but I want to edit him to be compatible with my needs, so I have 2 number boxes and I want when I put a number it shows me the sub total and the total but the code just get the first value of the first number box (adults) and shows me $Nan in the subtotal of the second number box and total. 
image 1 :
https://i.ibb.co/p3qFdNy/stackover.png).
But when i define var qty = qty1+qty2 
it shows me $Nan in everything.
Image 2 :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNkUy.png

```html
<input type="number" name="adult_count" id="adults"  required>
<input type="number" name="senior_count" id="senior"  required>
```

```
update_amounts();
        $('input').change(update_amounts);

        function update_amounts() {
            var sum = 0.0;
            $('#tickets > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
                var qty1 = $(this).find('#adults').val();
                var qty2 = $(this).find('#senior').val();
                var price = $(this).find('.price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/, '');
var qty = qty1 + qty 2;
                var amount = (qty * price);
                sum += amount;
                $(this).find('.subtotal').text('{{ \App\Helpers\Themes::getSymbolForCurrency() }}' + amount);
            });
            $('#total').val('{{ \App\Helpers\Themes::getSymbolForCurrency() }}' + sum);
        };
```

Comment: Typecasting.
The values coming from `.val()` maybe strings or another type you are not guaranteed of.
Use `var qty = Number(qty1) + Number(qty2)` and the same with price.

Comment: Nan means "Not-a-Number" value. This property indicates that a value is not a legal number, so you have to explicitly cast the values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the values to integer

```
var qty1 = parseInt($(this).find('#adults').val());
var qty2 = parseInt($(this).find('#senior').val());
```

Comment: Thanks for replying mate but when i put it in my code it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to parse but you declare the id of the textbox fields you don't need find them just

var qty1 = parseInt($('#adults').val());

var qty2 = parseInt($('#senior').val());

and you need to declare id attr of price field and total too
and post calculation you just need to put the calculated value into total field
like $('#Total').val(calculatedvalue);

Comment: Thanks for replying mate but when i put it in my code it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the values to integers AND handle non-number situations. In my example, 0 is used if it cant be parsed

```
  var qty1 = parseInt($(this).find('#adults').val()) || 0;
  var qty2 = parseInt($(this).find('#senior').val()) || 0;
```

Heres an example showing it in practice with your code (simplified):

https://jsfiddle.net/om5bxrck/

Comment: Thanks for replying mate but when i put it in my code it doesn't work :(